# Cannot install apps from Google Play Store due to insufficient space

Tags: google-play-store, sd-card, installation, insufficient-memory

I have an SD card which is 3 GB, but I only have 4 downloaded apps and the  internal storage almost reach its capacity and thus yet I have an insufficient space problems.

Comment: Generally, apps are installed on internal storage. Which Android device and Android version are you using? Meanwhile, check [insufficient-memory's info](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some general troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing cache for your internal storage and transfer "unimportant" files to your memory card, this will create some space for your apps to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106460/there-is-insufficient-space-on-the-device-in-lenovo-a3000/106464#106464) answer.

Apps are stored only on the `/data` partition, which is only a part of internal storage. So even though you have space on your SD card, (either internal or external), you may not have enough space to install your apps.

Comment: This is a great observation, but if you're posting it as an answer, be sure to propose a solution to the problem as well! (Not just a link).

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall the new Google Play Store App to factory settings every time you want to download a new/updated apps. I know this is a pain of a * but this works because it does not leave room for your Google to check updates, like Google books for daily newspapes or magazines which needs the space even if we do not use that app. I even hate how the new app looks and now in Google's newest version (5.3.6) they hide details for memory and price along with other details.

Comment: But that will result in waste of bandwidth. Every time you revert  to factory installed Play Store and launch it for downloading an app, it will first update itself to newest and then will install your app. Both could be done simultaneously too, but you got the point.