# There is insufficient space on the device in lenovo A3000

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory

I have a lenovo 3000 tablet. the tablet has 16 gb of internal memory but only 11 gb can be used. I can only install applications as much as 1 gb and if i want to update the apps i face with this error "“Error while downloading . There is insufficient space on the device” 
I've rooted tablet. How can I overcome this limitation and use that 11 gb for installing apps?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As that's a pretty frequent question here: Have you checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) and [its most frequented questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory?sort=frequent) already (in this order, I'd suggest)? I'm pretty sure that will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

To see your phone's internal partitions, enter terminal or ADB, and type "df". Your result will looks something like this:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   440.3M    48.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/secure            440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/asec              440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/obb               440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/system                755.9M   424.5M   331.4M   4096
/cache                 263.8M     4.4M   259.4M   4096
/data                    2.0G     1.1G   887.4M   4096
/mnt/modem              15.7M     4.2M    11.5M   4096
/mnt/log                78.7M     4.0M    74.7M   4096
/storage/sdcard1        29.0G     6.1G    22.9G   16384
/mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
/storage/sdcard0       499.0M     1.6M   497.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.google.android.ears-1     4.0M     2.2M     1.8M   4096
..../....
```

Look at the `/data` partition info: that's how many space the phone has for apps (apps are stored only on this partition (and they have their files on SD card, in case of apps with big data like games))

If it says that your partition is around 1GB (seems like that's what you described), and is almost full, there simply isn't enough memory to install more apps.

There are ways to change the data partition, it is possible to resize partitions (I've done this on my device), or you can move your /data partition to SD card, but all of these modifications require advanced knowledge, so be careful if you're not sure what you're doing.